# How to pair date rows in mysql

Tags: mysql

How to pair rows with imperfecty in mysql? Imperfect, meaning the rows are not exactly paired as in and out.  Sometimes, there are two in with one out or no out at all or two or more out with one in or no in at all.
The table look like this:

```
| id | action |        date         |
+----+--------+---------------------+
|  1 | in     | 19.1.2012  15:41:52 |
|  1 | out    | 19.1.2012  15:55:52 |
|  2 | in     | 19.2.2012  15:55:52 |
|  2 | out    | 19.2.2012  17:55:53 |
|  1 | in     | 19.3.2012  15:55:54 |
|  1 | in     | 19.3.2012  17:55:55 |
|  1 | out    | 19.3.2012  19:55:56 |
|  3 | in     | 19.4.2012  15:55:57 |
|  3 | out    | 19.4.2012  17:55:58 |
|  3 | out    | 19.4.2012  19:55:59 |
+----+--------+---------------------+
```

The desired result is like this:

```
+----+--------+---------------------+
| id | action |        date         |
+----+--------+---------------------+
|  1 | in     | 19.1.2012  15:41:52 |
|  1 | out    | 19.1.2012  15:55:52 |
|  2 | in     | 19.2.2012  15:55:52 |
|  2 | out    | 19.2.2012  17:55:53 |
|  1 | in     | 19.3.2012  17:55:55 |
|  1 | out    | 19.3.2012  19:55:56 |
|  3 | in     | 19.4.2012  15:55:57 |
|  3 | out    | 19.4.2012  17:55:58 |
+----+--------+---------------------+
```

This is the best desireed result

```
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
| id |       date_in       |      date_out       |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | 19.1.2012  15:41:52 | 19.1.2012  15:55:52 |
|  2 | 19.2.2012  15:55:52 | 19.2.2012  17:55:53 |
|  1 | 19.3.2012  17:55:55 | 19.3.2012  19:55:56 |
|  3 | 19.4.2012  15:55:57 | 19.4.2012  17:55:58 |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Here is a code, but it yields different result, can anyone figure out where the error is?
    enter code here SELECT c.e_id
     , CAST(c.in_time AS DATETIME) AS in_time
     , c.out_time
  FROM (
         SELECT IF(@prev_id = d.id,@in_time,@in_time:=NULL) AS reset_in_time
              , @in_time := IF(d.action = 'in',d.date,@in_time) AS in_time
              , IF(d.action = 'out',d.date,NULL) AS out_time
              , @prev_id := d.id  AS id
           FROM (
                  SELECT id, date_, action 
                    FROM e
                    JOIN (SELECT @prev_id := NULL, @in_time := NULL) f
                   ORDER BY id, date, action
                 ) d
       ) c
 WHERE c.out_time IS NOT NULL
 ORDER BY c.out_time `enter code here`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This selects an in event into a, an out event into b and uses a `LEFT JOIN` to eliminate the row if there exists an event c for the same id between them; that will simply get all in/out times that don't have an extra in or out between them.

```
SELECT a.id, a.date date_in, b.date date_out 
FROM mytable a
JOIN mytable b
  ON a.id = b.id AND a.date < b.date
LEFT JOIN mytable c
  ON a.id = c.id AND c.date < b.date AND c.date > a.date
WHERE a.action = 'in' AND b.action = 'out' AND c.action IS NULL
ORDER BY a.date;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7c1cb2/1).

Comment: nice solution but I noticed a bug that is, if there are two consecutive 'in's and then one 'out', it pairs the first in and the out.  The pairing should be last 'in' and the out.  The same happens when there is one 'in' and two consecutive 'out's.  It paired the in and the last out.  It should pair the in and the first out though.

Comment: @user3387779 Hm, if you look at the SQLfiddle, it seems to 100% match your desired result, that is, it matches last in with first out. Could you point out an example where it goes wrong?